# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.19.0 in multi-container deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a react application using two instances of nginx as React server and one as router. In practice, a first instance of nginx is use to route to the frontend (to the React application) when the request is different to " /api" (thus, easy application routing between pages) and when endpoint of the request start witn "/api". In the second case Nginx routes to backend server (Express server) that links to postgres or redis (depends on the type of data). In my local machine it works fine. When I deploy project on AWS elastic beanstalk (I use a CI instrument called Travis to do that) I don't have any error, except in running time. In the application I can route through different pages, but when I make a backend call, i.e. http://multidocker-env.eba-jqvdmh2c.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/all (you can try it by clicking) I have the following error:

[image]

The excercise should be able to calculate Fibonacci's chain of a number chosen by user. (try it on http://multidocker-env.eba-jqvdmh2c.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/). THe number chosen by client will go in postgres db, the  result of calculation instead, will go to redis. In production Elastic Beanstalk stored client project (react one), server project (backend express server with api endpoint), worker project (that it is able to make calculations) and nginx for routing between frontend and backend api. Postgres and redis are stored in two different AWS Service:

- Redis uses AWS ElastiCache
- Postgres uses AWS Relational Database Service (RDS)

Those are linked to Elastic Beanstalk using an environment variable settings:

[image]

I defined a Security group through every service also, in order to allow TCP traffic through ports from 5432 to 6379. This is my github repo

https://github.com/Aragorn1992gb/multi-docker4 and those are some the error logs:

```
    events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReplyError: MOVED 9411 172.31.10.162:6379
    at parseError (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:193:12)
    at parseType (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:303:14)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at Object.callbackOrEmit [as callback_or_emit] (/app/node_modules/redis/lib/utils.js:91:14)
    at RedisClient.return_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:706:11)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnError (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:572:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:278:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:217:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  command: 'HSET',
  args: [ 'values', '5', 'Nothing yet!' ],
  code: 'MOVED'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-04T14_09_13_153Z-debug.log

complete logs:
https://pastebin.com/rGcKiseq
```

As you can see, I used some "console.log" in server/index.js that you can see also in logs. But I can't figure out

Comment: You have `ETIMEDOUT` to RDS. Does the RDS security group allow connections from SG of EB instances?

Comment: Actually I forgot to share the security group between dbpostgres. Did that now, but problem still. https://imgur.com/csGGuul
This is the security gorup settings: https://imgur.com/QNI7ApE
On EC https://imgur.com/jw3cSf8

Comment: Can you click on it, and check ingress rules. And when you write that "In my local machine it works fine", does it mean that connections to RDS work from the local machine?

Comment: No because in local machine I user redis and postgres directly, in local. Thus I don't use AWS service, I use only docker

Comment: Maybe this can be a problem? IN Elastic Beanstalk: https://imgur.com/rYIxAh2
as you can se it selects two Groups. I tried to unslelect the first one and apply, but after thet it returns. MY Security group configurations: https://imgur.com/eqDfIm3
https://imgur.com/iOHzBJV

Comment: Something is blocking the connection to RDS. Typical suspects are SGs. Is the RDS in a private subnet?

Comment: How I can check if it is in a private subnet? I didn't set subnets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215299/discussion-between-marcin-and-alfonso-silvestri).

Comment: Hi @Marcin , I have updates about it. I send you a more clear log on the chat, check it